# Поиск по базе данных

Tags: поиск, php, mysql

Есть ли какая либо библиотека на php, которая позволяет организовать нормальный поиск в базе данных, учитывая морфологию русского языка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Первая же ссылка из гугла](http://valera.ws/2007.09.05~morpho_search_in_mysql/)